# Very large object dumped on each request

Tags: node.js, express

I have an application that I'm writing using express.js. When I run the application on my laptop, on each request, I see a very large object dumped as JSON to the console. It starts like this and goes on for many lines:

```
{ domain: null,
  _events: null,
  _maxListeners: 10,
  socket:
   { domain: null,
     _events:
      { drain: [Function: ondrain],
        timeout: [Object],
        error: [Function],
        close: [Object] },
     _maxListeners: 10,
     _handle:
      { writeQueueSize: 0,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread] },
     _pendingWriteReqs: 0,
     _flags: 0,
     _connectQueueSize: 0,
     destroyed: false,
     errorEmitted: false,
     bytesRead: 483,
     _bytesDispatched: 0,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     writable: true,
     readable: true,
     server:
```

The odd thing is that the exact same code doesn't do this on my PC. I guess this isn't an error as such but it means I can't see any useful output in the terminal. I'm at a loss as to why I'm getting this output.

Comment: you are seeing the output of a console.dir. Try to search your project files and remove it.

Comment: looks like a req or res, take a look at your middleware

Comment: I'm running the code on my PC right now (I use a VCS, obviously) and I _don't_ see the output. That's an important part of my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by deleting the node_modules directory in my project and than running npm install to re-download the required modules. Clearly something wasn't right in one of the modules.